# Getting a password in C without using getpass (3)?

Tags: c, passwords

I could use `getpass()` to get a password.  However, the man page says:

> This function is obsolete.  Do not use
>   it.

What is the current way to get a password from the user's terminal without echoing it, in a POSIX-compliant way?  [Originally I said "portably", but my intention was to avoid using an obsolete function.]

Comment: There is no portable way - this depends heavily on your platform.

Comment: @Jerry, it isn't worth it... even though it is LEGACY, it is the most portable way to go about it.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I agree. It's a strange decision to make `getpass()` obsolete and even removed from POSIX, without providing an alternative (like NetBSD's `getpass_r()`). Now everyone makes his/her own version, ridden with security/usability/portability bugs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this should work on linux/macosx, a windows version should use [Get/Set ConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167(VS.85).aspx)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct termios oflags, nflags;
    char password[64];

    /* disabling echo */
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
    nflags = oflags;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &nflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;
    printf("you typed '%s'\n", password);

    /* restore terminal */
    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &oflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems the most straightforward way to me.

Comment: You should use /dev/tty first before trying stdin, as if you're using a pipe, stdin would be the piped content, not the terminal input.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing char password[64] = {0}; or a memset before it is used if it is reentrant

Comment: `password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;` - this is incredibly wrong.

Comment: @ecatmur It is to remove the newline.  fgets already ensures the string fits and is nul-terminated.

Comment: `password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;` only removes the newline if it's there, else it wrongly removes the last character of the password.  `password[ strcspn( password, "\n" ) ] = '\0'` [works all the time](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.3).

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library to read from standard input without echoing the results to the screen. (Call `noecho()` before getting any input). The library has been around for ages and works on a wide variety of platforms (the windows version can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm))

Comment: I made a simple curses app (it's been a couple decaded since I used curses), and found that it cleared the screen when I did initscr().  There is probably some way around that, but it wasn't obvious from a quick perusal of the man pages.

Answer (score 5):

Even though this is a very old question that has already been answered, here's what I've been using (which is very similar to the accepted answer):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <cstdio>

//
// The following is a slightly modifed version taken from:
// http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html
//
ssize_t my_getpass (char *prompt, char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
{
    struct termios _old, _new;
    int nread;

    /* Turn echoing off and fail if we can’t. */
    if (tcgetattr (fileno (stream), &_old) != 0)
        return -1;
    _new = _old;
    _new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &_new) != 0)
        return -1;

    /* Display the prompt */
    if (prompt)
        printf("%s", prompt);

    /* Read the password. */
    nread = getline (lineptr, n, stream);

    /* Remove the carriage return */
    if (nread >= 1 && (*lineptr)[nread - 1] == '\n')
    {
        (*lineptr)[nread-1] = 0;
        nread--;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Restore terminal. */
    (void) tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &_old);

    return nread;
}

//
// Test harness - demonstrate calling my_getpass().
//
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t maxlen = 255;
    char pwd[maxlen];
    char *pPwd = pwd; // <-- haven't figured out how to avoid this.

    int count = my_getpass((char*)"Enter Password: ", &pPwd, &maxlen, stdin);

    printf("Size of password: %d\nPassword in plaintext: %s\n", count, pwd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me gusta.  This will even let you pipe in your password from the command line; however, if you're gonna do that then you may not want to print out a password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can probably use the `SetConsoleMode` api, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [University of Milwaukee's documentation](http://www.uwm.edu/cgi-bin/Dept/IMT/wwwman?topic=getpass) it is obsolete because:

> The `getpass()` function is not threadsafe because it manipulates
>   global signal state.
>
> The `getpass()` function is scheduled to be withdrawn from a future  version of the X/Open CAE Specification.

Comment: It's been withdrawn from POSIX/Single UNIX (the successor to X/Open) since 2001.

Comment: How is this an answer? This really should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution for Windows.
Include "conio.h"

```
  for (;;) {
  int c = _getch();
  switch (c)
  {
  case '\r':
  case '\n':
  case EOF:
    _putch('\n');
    break;

  default:
    _putch('*'); //mask
    thePassword += char(c);
    continue;
  }
  break;
}
```