# Ask user to enter Password, without showing the input characters on console?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enter Password in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634203/enter-password-in-c)

Ask user to enter Password without showing the input characters on console?

Comment: OS will be handy for this one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter Password in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634203/enter-password-in-c) and several others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the console to "no echo" mode. This depends on your particular OS. Here is an example of doing it for linux: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1988/page4.html#msg14522

Comment: @Gaurav: the link @Andrey posted has C code.

Answer (score 0):

See the [GNU libc documenation for getpass](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html), which gives a handy example of how to implement this:

```
 #include <termios.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 ssize_t
 my_getpass (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
 {
   struct termios old, new;
   int nread;

   /* Turn echoing off and fail if we can't. */
   if (tcgetattr (fileno (stream), &old) != 0)
     return -1;
   new = old;
   new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   if (tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &new) != 0)
     return -1;

   /* Read the password. */
   nread = getline (lineptr, n, stream);

   /* Restore terminal. */
   (void) tcsetattr (fileno (stream), TCSAFLUSH, &old);

   return nread;
 }
```