# What to use instead of getpass (and why is getpass obsolete)?

Tags: c, linux, passwords, obsolete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a password in C without using getpass (3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196418/getting-a-password-in-c-without-using-getpass-3)

```
man 3 getpass

DESCRIPTION
       This function is obsolete.  Do not use it.
```

I don't like in general the word "obsolete" or "deprecated" without "Use function 'X' instead" nearby.

What simple thing should I use to read a password from from user in CUI program in C on GNU/Linux? The password is for encryption/decryption, but not related to PAM,GPG,SSH or any other big thing.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1196418/1626345

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal