# How can I get password input without showing user input?

Tags: rust

How can I get password input without showing user input?

```
fn main() {
    println!("Type Your Password");

    // I want to hide input here, and do not know how
    let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("{}", input);
}
```

Comment: I think whether stdin is automatically echoed to stdout is controlled by the ECHO flag in some of the termios functions (under a POSIX system). A quick research on github showed some Rust bindings to it: https://github.com/nathan7/termios.rs. I haven't taken a deep look at this library so I can't tell how easy to use it will be, but you may find some useful information here.

Answer (score 21):

*Update:* you can use the [rpassword crate](https://crates.io/crates/rpassword). Quoting from the README:

Add the `rpassword` crate to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
rpassword = "0.0.4"
```

Then use the `read_password()` function:

```
extern crate rpassword;
    
use rpassword::read_password;
use std::io::Write;
    
fn main() {
    print!("Type a password: ");
    std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    let password = read_password().unwrap();
    println!("The password is: '{}'", password);
}
```

---

#### Old answer

I suspect your best bet is [calling some C functions from rust](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ffi.html): either [getpass (3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) or its recommended alternatives (see
[Getting a password in C without using getpass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196418/getting-a-password-in-c-without-using-getpass-3)). The tricky thing is that it differs by platform, of course (if you get it working, it'd be handy as a crate).

Depending on your requirements, you could also try using [ncurses-rs](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs) (crate "[ncurses](https://crates.io/crates/ncurses/)"); I haven't tested it but it looks like [example 2](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/master/examples/ex_2.rs) might demo turning off echoing input.

Comment: This works if run in cmd but fails if run in cygwin

Comment: As written, the prompt `Type a password: ` won't be shown on line-buffered stdout. You'll need to manually flush it (`std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();`).

Answer (score 0):

i'm new to rust so this actually took me a while to figure out but in the end i used TermRead to hide the password:

```
use termion::input::TermRead;
use std::io;

fn strip_nl(s: &mut String) -> String {
    if s.ends_with('\n') {
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r') {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    let out: String = s.to_string();
    out
}

fn prompt() -> (String, String) {
    let mut username = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut stdin = stdin;
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut stdout = stdout;

    println!("Enter Username:");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut username).expect("Failed to read username.");

    println!("Enter Password:");
    let passwd = TermRead::read_passwd(&mut stdin, &mut stdout);

    let Ok(Some(mut password)) = passwd else { todo!() };
    (strip_nl(&mut username), strip_nl(&mut password))
}

fn main() {
    let (username, password) = prompt();

    println!("");

    println!("{}, {}", username, password)
}
```