# Is there any mechanism in C to take password from user, like we have in JAVA as password field

Tags: c

Password, while typing should not be visible(stars should be visible instead of characters). Can it be done in C, as we have in JAVA.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but it is platform dependent and not related to the C language.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me some function which will work same.

Comment: If you tell us what platform you are on, you might get some useful answers.

Comment: Codeblocks , I guess

Comment: Please put al relevant information into the question as well. And Codeblocks is not a platform, but Linux and Windows are.

Comment: Then kindly suggest for both man!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better alternative for getpass function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396188/better-alternative-for-getpass-function)

Comment: Is this a command line application or are you using some widget toolkit? There's nothing in C to do with passwords, much the same as there's nothing in C to get weather forecasts, but all can be implemented. Unless you want accurate weather forecasts...

Comment: I am expecting a simple C code!!! in any platform and not downvotes.

Comment: @DeepakAhire There is an Answer for you, but are you sure you need it for C only, does GTK helps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a linux platform and terminal you must modify terminal behavior, disabling echoing and using non canonical mode

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static struct termios oldPar, newPar;

void initTermios(bool echo) {
    tcgetattr(0, &oldPar);
    newPar = oldPar;
    newPar.c_lflag &= (tcflag_t)~ICANON;
    newPar.c_lflag &= echo ? (tcflag_t)ECHO : (tcflag_t)~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newPar);
}

void resetTermios(void) {
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldPar);
}

char getch_(bool echo) {
    int ch;
    initTermios(echo);
    ch = getchar();
    resetTermios();
    return (char)ch;
}

char getch(void) {
    return getch_(false);
}

int main(void) {
    char c;
    char psw[16] = { 0 };
    size_t index = 0;
    printf("Insert password: ");
    do
    {
        c = getch();
        printf("*");

        psw[index++]= c;

    }
    while ((index < (sizeof(psw)-1)) && (c!='\n'));

    printf("\n\nPassword: %s\n", psw);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;` You are using `new` Here?

Comment: @Michi I'm not getting you, but I edited changing the name of that var, if that was the problem.

Comment: how about [fixing this](http://pastebin.com/raw/LdxPVbc9)?

Comment: @Michi What is your platform? What are you compilation flags? Nothing triggered on my Linux platform with gcc 4.9.2 with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`

Comment: You are using an verry old Compiler version, I'm on GCC-6 with ==>>>: `-Wpedantic -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -O0 -g`

Comment: any way in `char getch_(int echo)⅞°`  `char ch` should be `int ch` and the function should also return int or at least you need a cast there like `return (char)ch;`

Comment: @Michi Yes it is, on some exotic platform can be a problem. I'm editing

Comment: Your code still need to be fixed `negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type` Here ==> `newPar.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;` and Here =>> `newPar.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO;`

Comment: @Michi Not my aim here, in a too broad question. Fill free to post your own (better) answer...

Comment: Sir, I'm not judge you or your Answer, I'm just telling you that your code should be fixed. I will not post another Answer, when you gave already a good one. Fixing those two lines makes it fine.

Comment: I forgot to tell you about my Platform as you asked. I'm on Linux mint with GGC-6. There is a cast needed there on (unsigned)~ICANON and (unsigned)~ECHO and compiles fine

Comment: @Michi I know, I'll edit,. This due to the "bad" implementation of that literals that are octet instead of Hex. I really don't know why ..?

Comment: I also changed in  `void initTermios(unsigned echo);` and `char getch_(unsigned echo);`  ==> echo to `unsigned`

Comment: @Michi I edited, in a different way, but your is correct too.