# Password in star form

Tags: c, windows

i want this password code in star form.
anyone can help.

```
/*password*/
        LOGINP:
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\n\n\n\nUsername: its_vishuuuu");
    gotoxy(x,y);
    printf("Login\n\n\t\t\tPassword: ");
    fflush(stdin);//covert char to int screen
    gets(pass1);//enter string
    check=strcmp(pass1,password1);//check password
    if(check!=0)
    {
        clrscr();
        goto LOGINP;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Linux console, then after each character is read, print `char(8)` (Ctrl-H), which is [backspace](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html), then print an asterisk to overwrite the character that was just input.

Comment: i m using windows turbo c++ software

Comment: That makes a difference. I added the [tag:windows] tag for you. The more details you give us, the better that we can help you. Good luck

Comment: Sir then what will i use if i dont use goto

Comment: `while (1)` will loop forever, but your code should probably not loop if the password is valid :-)  So, make a variable `validPassword`, initialize it to zer0, use `while (validPassord == 0` and `if(check!=0) validPassword = 1`;

Comment: So, but we don't do homework here. You have all the information that you need. Try your best, and if it doesn't work, post another question. I don't mean to be cruel, but you won't learn if others write your code. In the worst case, hand it in with the` goto` & have your teacher or lecturer tell you why `goto` is bad.

Comment: what is printf("%c",177);

Comment: That prints ascii character 177 - see https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html - character 8 is backspace

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can use [getpass()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html#:~:targetText=The%20getpass()%20function%20opens,closes%20%2Fdev%2Ftty%20again.) function. And for alternative see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32396815/9248466).

Comment: i m using windows turbo c++ software

Comment: @its_vishuuuu It's better to use MSVC Compiler on Windows and follow [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/) for learning basic of C++ and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/9248466) link for a book.

Comment: sir i am a student of bca 1st semester at present i learn c language i dont know about c++