# On linux, when programming with C/C++, what function should I use for inputting password?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu20.04. When programming with C/C++ to create CLI applications, I'd like to be able to input something private such as password. In particular, I need my input not showing on the screen when I type the password.

---

**Update:**

Not sure why this is closed for not having enough focus. I think I have been as specific as possible:

- Platform: ubuntu 20.04
- Language: C/C++
- What I am doing: to create a CLI application that allows me to input passwords.
- What I want: the input not showing on my screen while I am typing it.

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's because I was asking for the C++ solution and the Python solution at the same time, I've already edited the question.

Comment: @tdelaney: The man page for [`getpass()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) says `This function is obsolete.  Do not use it.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196418/getting-a-password-in-c-without-using-getpass-3 might be useful, although it uses c i/o instead of c++.

Comment: @BillLynch Thanks. I'll take a look. c i/o is also okay for me.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, but the question's title did strike me as strange. It might be better to gear the title towards the more general case, along the lines of "Getting user input without it displayed in the console". Your question is already somewhat oriented on the general case, but it's also a bit short. Perhaps you are simply being concise, but you might want to give the question a once-over with a mindset centered on the general case.

Comment: @JaMiT I dare not make it more general than this...it is already closed for "needs more focus".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terminal I/O` api to do this.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    unsigned char c;

    /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&old_tio);

    /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
    new_tio=old_tio;

    /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
    new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);

    /* set the new settings immediately */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);

    int i = 0;
    char password[100] = {0}; // hardcode with max 100 char input
    do {
         c=getchar();
         password[i++] = c;
         printf("*");
    } while(c!='\n' || i == 100);

    printf("%s\n", password);

    /* restore the former settings */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);

    return 0;
}
```